# style Visibility:visible is not working intermittently on IE11(works fine on chrome and firefox)

Tags: css, sass, internet-explorer-11, visibility, opacity

I have a pop up on button click to be displayed on the view.I'm using `visibility: visible` to show the popup it works fine with chrome and firefox and the class is getting inherited from the design system itself.where as on IE11 it's transparency is high while I want it to be opaque.can I overwrite the parent class which is getting inherited from the design system? or any other solution
I have tried with

```
opacity: 1;
z-index: 1;
background-color: rgba(white,100%);
transition: opacity 200ms;
visibility: visible
```

Nothing works while tried with `!important` too or overwriting the inherited class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by increasing transition : opacity 200ms to transition :opacity 500ms it works fine now the popup is opaque not transparent as i expected

```
opacity: 1;
z-index: 1;
background-color: rgba(white,100%);
transition: opacity 500ms;
visibility: visible
```

Comment: Please mark your answer as the accepted answer. It can help other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please provide [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I made a simple sample to change the style and `visibility: visible` can work well in IE 11:

```js
function changecss() {
  document.getElementById("test").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```css
#test {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(white, 100%);
  transition: opacity 200ms;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="changecss()" />
<div id="test">test pop up!</div>
```

If it doesn't solve your issue, please provide a code snippet including related html, css and javascript to reproduce the issue, so that we can test on our side and see how to help.

Comment: Thank you @Yu Zhou   ...i resolved this by increasing transition : opacity 200ms  to transition :opacity 500ms it works fine now the popup is opaque not transparent as i expected

Comment: Cheers! You can also post your solution as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer after 48hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.